# Hibernate generates 2 inserts instead of update after upgrade to java 11

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8, spring-data-jpa, java-11

I migrated my app to java 11 by changing maven-compiler plugin target and source to 11 from 1.8

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>11</source>
            <target>11</target>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <compilerArguments>
                <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
            </compilerArguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

then added needed dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and that's it. App loads up and to an extent works but it fails to save an entity. The part of the code that fails worked perfectly in java8 but fails in java 11.

the code is

```
LoginRequest req = ...;

LoginAttempt la = service.saveLoginAttempt(...); // saveLoginAttempt has transactional annotation
Result result = client.authorize(req);
updateLoginAttempt(result, la); // this method does too
```

in the end all it does is uses `JpaSpecRepository` and calls save method. in java 8 no problem, after calling saveLoginAttempt it insert the entity and then after calling updateLoginAttempt it updates the entity by genearting update sql.

in java 11, first call does nothing and upon calling save second time (in the updateLoginAttemmpt method) it generates 2 inserts and fails with unique id violation exception... any idea what could this be?

Comment: Have you updated your Spring/JPA and Hibernate dependencies?
You might need to do that as well.

Comment: https://nipafx.dev/java-11-migration-guide# might give you some ideas :) Please read

Comment: I tried simulating the error in tests to no avail, it just works there. I checked the tutorial but no luck either. I'm thinking of starting a bounty...